# Running into undefined method `price_cents'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, money-rails

Have added `money-rails` gem to my app.

Migrated its column to my model `Item`

**Migration**

```
class AddPriceToItems < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_column :items, :price, :money
  end
end
```

**Model Item**

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :invoice

  validates_numericality_of :unit_price, :quantity 

  monetize :price_cents

end
```

**Schema**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170223211329) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "invoices", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.decimal  "unit_price", precision: 10, scale: 2
    t.integer  "quantity"
    t.integer  "invoice_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.money    "price",                     scale: 2
    t.index ["invoice_id"], name: "index_items_on_invoice_id", using: :btree
  end

  add_foreign_key "items", "invoices"
end
```

This is the error that I'm running into

```
undefined method `price_cents' for #<Item:0x007f9f6b366ae8>
Did you mean?  price_cents=
```

Not sure how to resolve this.

**EDIT**

Ok, I dropped the price column, and have added it back as price_cents column as integer ...

However, should it be this in the schema:

`t.integer  "price_cents"` ..

**OR**

`t.monetize  "price_cents"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of your column needs to be `price_cents` not `price`.

The type of your column needs to be `integer`.

I think you tried to copy

```
add_money :products, :price
```

but you used `add_column` instead of `add_money`.

I used this gem recently but the `add_money` helper was undefined so I used

```
add_column :items, :price_cents, :integer
```

I don't think it will work with a `money` column type

Comment: ... again, in other words, drop the original `price` column and add it back as `price_center` and as integer ... ? I'm kind of confused about what I did ... not sure how I did `money` column instead of `monetize` since that's for Rails 4x and up ...

Comment: `t.integer  "price_cents"`

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to make sure that the money amount you are adding/multiplying doesn't give inaccurate sums or products (like $14.099..), then you may consider going this path:

1) When generating your Items model use this
`price:monetize`

2) In your migration file, this will reflect as:
`t.monetize :price`

3) After running `rails db:migrate`, this will produce two columns in your ItemsTable:
The first column will be `price_cents` ( which will be the amount of the item in cents, (eg 1000 = $10)
The second column will be price_currency (e.g. $), the default is USD in the schema.rb

`t.integer  "price_cents",    default: 0,     null: false
 t.string   "price_currency", default: "USD", null: false`

Answer (score 0):

Your model should have an integer (not money type) price_cents column, not price. The symbol passed to monetize should be that column. See here: https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails#usage-example

Comment: in other words, drop the current column in the Items table, and added it back as integer and full name as `price_cents`?